# Python; add blank screen after words in a split sentence

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm building a Psychopy experiment that presents sentences one word at a time and then presents a separate word that collects a response. My input for the first part is a whole sentence which I split into words in the code and which updates on each frame to display the current word in the sentence for 300 ms. Now I am a coding noob and I can't figure out how to add a blank screen for 300 ms after each word is presented.

Sentence: "John kicked the bucket"
Split into words, presented as: John(300ms) blankscreen(300ms) kicked(300ms) blankscreen(300ms) etc.

I've included my relevant code but somehow cannot figure out how to get the blank screen in between the updating words. I've tried creating a blankscreen image and inserting it into the loop at different places but I can't figure it out. Help would be much appreciated!

```
    # get the sentence for this trial and split it into a list of words:
words = Sentence.split() 

# count them (the length of the list): 
numWords = len(words)

# how long the text component should display for: 
totalDuration = numWords * 0.3 # time in seconds 

fixationDuration = 1.5 # put in whatever your actual fixation duration is 
currentWordIndex = -1 # will be useful in "each frame" tab

# t is the time elapsed in the trial. 
# Calculate what word we should be up to by seeing how many 300 ms periods have elapsed so far (& force it to be an integer): 
checkIndex = int((t-fixationDuration)/0.3) 

# see if we need to switch to a new word (including the very first one): 
if checkIndex < numWords:
    if checkIndex != currentWordIndex: 
        currentWordIndex = checkIndex 
        text_1.setText(words[currentWordIndex]) # update to the current word
```

Now a few iterations later, I have a functioning stand-alone script that splits a sentence and on each trial would present a fixation cross for 1,5 seconds (90 frames) and then presents each word in the split sentence for 300ms each with blanks of 300 ms inbetween. However, I can't get this to function in my larger script that takes 200 sentences as input. When I try to incorporate it in my Builder part of Psychopy (I would like to keep it Builder compatible for students), it only presents the first sentence over and over (fixation cross, word, blank, etc to end of sentence, then fixation again and the same sentence). Each trial should look like this:

- Fixation cross 1.5 seconds / 90 frames (60Hz)
- Word / blank / word / blank presentation of the sentence
- Target word that participants have to respond to

Right now the target word is a separate routine in Builder, but that does not seem to be the reason why the script does not work. It's unable to keep track of which sentence it is supposed to present as that's not built into it right now (and obviously I replace the "John kicked the bucket" sentence with my Sentence variable which is a list of all sentences), and just presents the same one however many times as there are words in the sentence it has split. This is why I thought I needed the checkIndex variable. I think I need some sort of index that checks each frame how many frames have been presented, so that it knows whether to update my text_1 stim to the next word or not.

```
    from psychopy import visual
    from psychopy import core

    words = "He kicked the bucket".split() 
    win = visual.Window()
    text_1 = visual.TextStim(win)

    text_1.setText("+")
    for frameN in range (90):
       text_1.draw()
       win.flip()

    for word in words:

        text_1.setText(word)
        for frameN in range (18):
           text_1.draw()
           win.flip()

        text_1.setText(" ")
        for frameN in range(18):
           text_1.draw()
           win.flip()
```

Comment: Oh, so you're using Builder! Have you entered the code in the "Begin Routine" tab? The behavior could sound like it's in the "begin experiment" tab.

Comment: I had the variable definition in "begin routine" and the code from "for word for words:" onwards in "each frame" before, so that was probably one issue. If I move all of it into "begin routine" however, it crashes because of win = visual.Window(). Might be a computer issue after all then? I'll try to run it at home, as drawing text_1 twice didn't help. Would be an issue for running it on lab computers then. Thanks for your patience and help, the "I don't know what I'm doing" factor is pretty high for me.

Comment: It works! In another attempt right now I put the code above into the "begin routine" and had to take out the visual.Window code parts and create an actual text stimulus placeholder in my Builder experiment for it to refer to, and then it works. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

See a solution below.

An important thing to keep in mind here is you should time visual stimuli using discrete monitor frames/updates rather than continuous time. For example, using `core.wait(0.300)` will often cause the text to arrive at the next frame, resulting in a real interval of 316.7 ms on some trials but 300 ms on others. The `visual.Window.flip()` function halts everything until the monitors updates, so looping over `flip()` will synchronize the loop with the monitor - useful!

```py
from psychopy import visual
words = 'John kicked the bucket'.split()
win = visual.Window()
text_1 = visual.TextStim(win)

for word in words:
    # Set text for this trial
    text_1.text = word

    # Show text for 300 ms = 18 frames on 60Hz monitor
    for frame in range(18):
        text_1.draw()
        win.flip()

    # Blank screen for 300 ms = 18 frames on 60Hz monitor
    for frame in range(18):
        win.flip()  # OBS: no drawing in this loop. Just a blank screen.
```

It does require that your computer actually synchronizes to the monitor. And if you run a different refresh rate than 60 Hz, change the number of frames, so that you get the desired 300 ms. If you use psychopy, run Coder --> demos --> timing --> timesByFrames and you should see a narrow distribution around 16.667 ms on a 60Hz monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have been working on this for hours now and it won't work. When I run your script, it only shows me the word "bucket". I've tried several iterations and combinations of the scripts, and to me it seems like I really do need some sort of checkIndex component in there to keep track of what word the script should be presenting. It does not seem to be as simple.

Right now I have about 17 iterations of the experiment, all of which do something different yet wrong (like present no words on trial 1, 1 word on trial 2, 2 words on trial 3 etc.) and I'm lost.

Comment: Addittion: I do have a version close to yours that presents words and blanks correctly but messes up on the fixation cross. I will try to post this by Friday.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then something is wrong specifically on your computer. Try running the script on a different computer - preferably with a dedicated graphics card. I expect it to work there. But possible solutions to make it work on your computer is: (1) upgrade your graphics driver, (2) make a second ``text_1.draw()`` line just before the current one (draw twice).

Comment: It's not a computer issue, it seems to be an issue with it working as a separate coder script in Psychopy with one sentence, but it does not work when I try to adjust it and incorporate it into my larger script that takes 200 sentences from an input file, splits them and shows each sentences' words on a different trial, followed by a target word after each sentence. I edited my original post to include the current status. Thanks again for any help, this is my first script so I am figuring it out as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Issue has been solved. This code goes into the "begin routine" part of Builder:

```
 # get the sentence for this trial and 
 # split it into a list of words: 
 words = Sentence.split() 

 text_2.setText("+") #draw a fixation cross at the beginning of each trial for 90 frames
for frameN in range (90):
    text_2.draw()
    win.flip()

for word in words:

    text_2.setText(word) #set current word in Builder placeholder text variable
    for frameN in range (18):
           text_2.draw() #present current word for 18 frames
           win.flip()

    for frameN in range(18): #present blank screen for 18 frames
           win.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

words = sentence.split()

for word in words:
    #place something to undo changes in blank screen, you can use try except
    text_1.setText(word)
    time.sleep(.3)
    text_1.setText("") 
    #make changes during blank screen, put images or something
    time.sleep(.3)
```

I guess this should do what you want if I understood your question correctly. In place of `text_1.setText("")`, place whatever you want to do when you want to display blank screen.

Comment: You should have a ``text_1.draw()`` and ``visual.Window.flip()`` after each ``setText`` to actually show it. See my answer for an improved-timing solution.